# Loading image from byte array failed on iis

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I have an image (`byte[]`) in `SQL` server. When I convert this to an image source on localhost it works fine. But when it runs from `IIS` server with an `IP` the web page loading indefinitely.

My code is follows:

```
    void LoadCertificate()
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString);
            cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "sp_getCertificateInfoForReport";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpCode", TextBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyID", 1);
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            conn.Open();
            da.Fill(dt);
            conn.Close();
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    byte[] bytes = (byte[])dt.Rows[i]["CImage"];
                    var divHtml = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
                    div.ID = "test";
                    Label lbl = new Label();
                    lbl.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Description"].ToString();
                    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
                    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);


                    img.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64String;
                    img.Height = 400;
                    img.Width = 300;
                    img.AlternateText = "Test image";
                    div.Controls.Add(lbl);
                    div.Controls.Add(img);
                    Certificate.Controls.Add(div);             
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ll)
        {

        }

    }
```

In my aspx page:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="290px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />

</div>
<div ID="Certificate" runat="server">

</div>
</form>
```

That code works fine on localhost but why it failed after published on IIS?

Comment: What is an error it shows? Have you tried with static image which is already stored in project directory

Comment: You're swallowing the exception with the `catch (Exception ll)`, so whatever is going wrong, you're not able to see the error generated.

Comment: no exception occurs but the page is loading forever  @PrashantPimpale

Comment: Did you change the connection string for server use? If it is wrong the website will load until there is a timeout.